# Converting real data type to nvarchar changes the original value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a problem in that I have created a #TmpTbl in in my stored proc which inserts a value into a field with a REAL data type. When I write this value to another table which has a data type of NVARCHAR(200) it changes the original value.

REAL data type value = 2122222 the converted NVARCHAR data type value = 2122220

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use STR
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

```
create table t (i int,x nvarchar(200))

declare @x real = 2122222 

insert into t (i,x) select 1,@x
insert into t (i,x) select 2,str (@x)

select * from t order by i
```

---

```
+---+--------------+
| i | x            |
+---+--------------+
| 1 | 2.12222e+006 |
+---+--------------+
| 2 | 2122222      |
+---+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.